# Updating rank in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as below

```
ID_STUDENT | ID_CLASS | GRADE
-----------------------------
1       |    1     |  90
1       |    2     |  80
2       |    1     |  99
3       |    1     |  80
4       |    1     |  70
5       |    2     |  78
6       |    2     |  90
6       |    3     |  50
7       |    3     |  90
```

I need to then group, sort and order them and update the assigned rank :

```
ID_STUDENT | ID_CLASS | GRADE | RANK
------------------------------------
2      |    1     |  99   |  1
1      |    1     |  90   |  2
3      |    1     |  80   |  3
4      |    1     |  70   |  4
6      |    2     |  90   |  1
1      |    2     |  80   |  2
5      |    2     |  78   |  3
7      |    3     |  90   |  1
6      |    3     |  50   |  2
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this in mysql .

Comment: You can do this using variables. There are plenty of examples here in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will sorts the results group by `ID_CLASS` and in the descending order of `GRADE` columns.

**Query**

```
select `ID_STUDENT`, `ID_CLASS`, `GRADE`, ( 
    case `ID_CLASS`
    when @curA then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
    else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `ID_CLASS` end
) as `rank`
from `your_table_name` g,
(select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r
order by `ID_CLASS`, `GRADE` desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID_STUDENT,ID_CLASS,GRADE,RANK 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ID_STUDENT,ID_CLASS,GRADE,CASE WHEN @ID_CLASS=ID_CLASS THEN @RANK:= @RANK+1 ELSE @RANK :=1 END RANK,@ID_CLASS:=ID_CLASS
    FROM STUDENT_TABLE,(SELECT @RANK :=0,@ID_CLASS:=1)Z ORDER BY ID_CLASS ASC,GRADE DESC
)ZZ;
```

You can try above query.

Here is [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83705a/1)

Answer (score 0):

We can use session variables here to simulate the rank.  Note carefully that you are really after the *rank*, and not just the row number.  The reason for this is that two or more students in a given class could be tied with the same grade.  Your sample data did not include such an edge case, but the case is present in your problem.  I chose to use the dense rank here, which means that if a class had give students with the following grades:

```
student | grade | dense rank
1       | 90    | 1
2       | 90    | 1
3       | 90    | 1
4       | 80    | 2
5       | 65    | 3
```

then a three-way tie for the highest grade would mean that all three students would be first, with the next highest student coming in at second.  The alternative would be to use the rank, in which case the next highest student would have rank 4.

```
SET @dr = 1;
SET @id_class = NULL;
SET @grade = NULL;

SELECT
    ID_STUDENT,
    @dr:=CASE WHEN (@id_class = ID_CLASS AND @grade <> GRADE) THEN @dr + 1
              WHEN (@id_class = ID_CLASS AND @grade = GRADE) THEN @dr
              ELSE 1 END AS dr,
    @id_class:=ID_CLASS AS ID_CLASS,
    @grade:=GRADE AS GRADE
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ID_CLASS,
    GRADE DESC;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Hi sorry i was wrong in my question . I am trying to rank the ID_CLASS , not based on grade , there might be n number of duplicate id_class I am trying to assign and update rank for those id_class .

Comment: @lakshmanaBabu I spent 30 minutes of my time answering your question.  Did you care to spend even 2 minutes actually reading my answer?  I answered your question correctly.  If there are no ties, then dense rank and row number behave identically.

Comment: I don't recommend actually storing these values in your table, just generate them when you query.

Comment: Thank you for your Time Tim . I tried and working fine but i am trying to rank for every class_id for example if i have id_class repeated 5 times i wanna rank it 1-5 and so on for all other classed , I was able to assign rank but facing issues while trying to update that rank also  Generating them in query is fine since  i need to perform one more operation to select percentage of record  I am trying to update the rank .

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE youre_tbl t2
SET t2 .RANK= (SELECT *
                 FROM youre_tbl t
                 ORDER BY t.GRADE)
FROM t2
WHERE t2.ID = t.ID
```

You can get ordered result from this.

Answer (score -1):

[image]i have seem u r question and find out ans as per u r need.
i think help below query to find data proper format.

```
SELECT * FROM `temp_u` GROUP BY `ID_STUDENT` ORDER by `RANK` ASC
```

Comment: From where you got the `rank` column?

Comment: I was able to get ordered comment using rank , but when i try to update the assigned rank into table its not working .

Comment: I think u need to add one column for unique key for update rank for ex. rank_id in before ID_STUDENT and using this rank_id  u can easy update rank.